# SQL server 2014 calculating hours in between

Tags: sql, ssms

I am having trouble with calculating something in a query and need some help!  Here is the sample data table:

| PERSONNUM | PunchStart | PunchEnd | PayCodeName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100038 | 2023-05-06 07:30:00.000 |  | REST VIOLATION |
| 100038 | 2023-05-07 14:30:00.000 | 2023-05-07 15:30:00.000 | RECALL |
| 100038 | 2023-05-07 16:30:00.000 | 2023-05-07 18:00:00.000 | RECALL |
| 100038 | 2023-05-08 07:30:00.000 |  | REST VIOLATION |
| 97976 | 2023-05-06 07:30:00.000 |  | REST VIOLATION |
| 97976 | 2023-05-07 14:30:00.000 | 2023-05-07 15:30:00.000 | RECALL |
| 97976 | 2023-05-07 16:30:00.000 | 2023-05-07 18:00:00.000 | RECALL |
| 97976 | 2023-05-08 07:30:00.000 |  | REST VIOLATION |

What I need to calculate is, the total number of recall hours that exist between each REST VIOLATION row.

Final output would look like this:

| PERSONNUM | PunchStart | PunchEnd | PayCodeName | Recall in between |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100038 | 2023-05-06 07:30:00.000 |  | REST VIOLATION | 0 |
| 100038 | 2023-05-08 07:30:00.000 |  | REST VIOLATION | 2.5 |
| 97976 | 2023-05-06 07:30:00.000 |  | REST VIOLATION | 0 |
| 97976 | 2023-05-08 07:30:00.000 |  | REST VIOLATION | 2.5 |

I've tried CTE tables, subqueries, window functions and ChatGPT but keep coming up short...

Comment: Please add your attempt to your question

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should probably give you a reasonable start, and you can tweak as needed.  (Obviously, you haven't specifically noted the name of your table)

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT
        PERSONNUM,
        PunchStart,
        (
            SELECT TOP 1
            t2.PunchStart
            FROM yourTable t2
            WHERE t2.PERSONNUM = t1.PERSONNUM
            AND t2.PunchStart < t1.PunchStart
            ORDER BY t2.PunchStart DESC
        ) AS [PriorPunchStart]
    FROM yourTable t1
)
SELECT
    PERSONNUM,
    PunchStart,
    PriorPunchStart,
    (ISNULL((
        SELECT 
            DATEDIFF(minute, recall.PunchStart, recall.PunchEnd)
        FROM yourTable recall
        WHERE recall.PERSONNUM = x.PERSONNUM
        AND recall.PunchStart > ISNULL(x.PriorPunchStart, x.PunchStart)
        AND recall.PunchEnd < x.PunchStart
    ), 0.0) / 60.0) AS [RecallHours]
FROM x
```